# Can I return an IEnumerable<T> rather than IEnumerable<Node<T>> with CollectAs in Neo4J .net client

Tags: neo4jclient

Can I have the CollectAs function return `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<Node<T>>`?  I'd like to keep out database specific classes like Neo4j.Node from my POCO classes.  I have to use a named class since with the client because the alternative relationship is optional and using a generic class would give me noresults.  The other alternative would be for me to create an intermediary class like AppDetailWithNodes and then transform that into a POCO class but it seems like a bit of a chore to have an extra class for that.

```
var query = client.Cypher.StartWithNodeIndexLookup("root", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, appSlug)
 .Match("root <-[?:Alternative]-Alternatives") 
 .Return((root, Alternatives) => new AppDetail()
   {
     App = root.As<App>(),
     Alternatives = Alternatives.CollectAs<App>()
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher always gives us `Node<T>` in the table whether we just want `T` or not.

We have some smarts in Neo4jClient that allow you to use `Return<T>` instead of `Return<Node<T>>`, and then we'll throw this information away for you. We're still returning it over the wire though.

These smarts haven't been implemented for `CollectAs`.

For now, you'll just need to project it away in .NET:

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .StartWithNodeIndexLookup("root", AUTOINDEX, PrimaryIndexKey, appSlug)
    .Match("root <-[?:Alternative]-alternative")
    .Return((root, alternative) => new
    {
        App = root.As<App>(),
        Alternatives = alternative.CollectAs<App>()
    })
    .Results
    .Select(result => new AppDetail()
    {
        App = result.App,
        Alternatives = result.Alternatives.Select(a => a.Data).ToArray()
    });
```

Using an anonymous type for the `Return` call will save you from having to create the `AppDetailWithNodes` intermediary class.

Comment: thanks, for the response.  Is there still the issue with anonymous types preventing some results (those without the relationship) from being returned when there is an optional relationship?

Comment: If you're getting an exception, please report it at https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issues/new

If you're missing records, then it's likely something in your query, so you should follow the debugging steps on https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher

Comment: Issue already in there I think https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/67/error-on-using-collect-function-in

Comment: Also relevant: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/77/support-collectas-returning-t-instead-of